# How to implement X.PagedList PagedListPager using attribute routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, pagedlist

**Background**

I'm using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core v8.1.0 in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 project.

I have an action with the following route attribute:

```cs
[Route("[controller]/{Foo1Param}/{Foo2Param}")]
public IActionResult FooAction(int page, string foo1Param, string foo2Param)
```

I have the following Razor for writing out the default style pager:

```
@using X.PagedList; @*import this so we can cast our list to IPagedList (only necessary because ViewBag is dynamic)*@
@model IPagedList;
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core; @*import this so we get our HTML Helper*@
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("FooAction", new { page, foo1Param = "foo1", foo2Param = "foo2" }))
```

**Initial issue**

When using the PagedListPager, the URL being constructed left the foo1Param and foo2Param as part of the query string, instead of the URL path.

I.e.

```
https://hostname/controller/fooaction?page=2&foo1Param=foo1&foo2Param=foo2
```

Instead of

```
https://hostname/controller/fooaction/foo1/foo2?page=2
```

**Investigation**

I found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#url-generation-and-ambient-values) that Url.Action does support attribute routing and I got the expected URL using both the Url.Action...

```
@Url.Action("FooAction", new { foo1Param = "foo1", foo2Param = "foo2" })
```

...as well as using the tag helper:

```html
<a asp-action="FooAction" asp-route-foo1param="foo1" asp-route-foo2param="foo2">Foo link</a>
```

**NOTE:** The working examples above don't use the page parameter as this is specific to the PagedListPager.

As well as the above I found this article on [codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1210556/Replacing-the-query-string-in-the-URL-generated-by) which gave me something to try.

As a result of this, I added an additional route to give the full route of:

```cs
[Route("[controller]/{Foo1Param}/{Foo2Param}")]
[Route("[controller]/{Foo1Param}/{Foo2Param}/page={page:int}")]
```

**Issue**

The PagedListPager does now route to the path but the URL is in the structure:

```
https://hostname/controller/fooaction/foo1/foo2/page%3D2
```

Rather than:

```
https://hostname/controller/fooaction/foo1/foo2?page=2
```

The URL shows the equal sign encoded and I'm unable to use a ? in the route to move the page to a parameter as this gives a compile time error.

```
Literal sections cannot contain the '?' character
```

Any suggestions on how to give the required URL of the below, using the PagedListPager:

```
https://hostname/controller/fooaction/foo1/foo2?page=2
```

**Edit:**

I have the following configured in startup:

```cs
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
             {
                 endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                 endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
             });
```

Comment: Check the route attribute, the route templates don't contain the action parameter, I checked the [X.PagedList](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList), with the following code: `@Html.PagedListPager(pagedList, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, foo1Param = "foo1", foo2Param = "foo2" }))` and `[Route("[controller]/[action]/{page}/{Foo1Param}/{Foo2Param}")]`. The url like this:`https://localhost:44326/Home/Index/5/foo1/foo2`, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5puYM.png). You could try to use the above route template.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The reason your route is working is because you've put {page} as part of the route which seems to be what PagedListPager needs to map to it. If you take {page} out, I'd expect this route wouldn't work? I'm looking for the URL pattern of ```https://hostname/controller/fooaction/foo1/foo2?page=5``` as this keeps things consistent with my other X.PagedList pages rather than ```https://hostname/controller/fooaction/5/foo1/foo2```. Any further ideas?

Comment: Try to change the route attribute as below: `[Route("[controller]/[action]/{Foo1Param}/{Foo2Param}")]`, then the url pattern is `https://localhost:44326/Home/Index/foo1/foo2?page=6` , refer [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCdgj.png)

Comment: Unable to get this to work. I have a more complicated scenario than my eg where I was binding other properties via a view model and my fooParams being Enums rather than strings but I stripped this back to ```[Route("[controller]/[action]/{Foo1Param}/{Foo2Param}")]```, ```public IActionResult FooAction(string foo1Param, string foo1Param)```, ```@Html.PagedListPager(fooList, page => Url.Action("FooAction", "FooController", new { page, foo1Param = "foo1", foo2Param = "foo2" }))``` gives me ```https://hostname/foocontroller/fooaction?page=2&foo1Param=foo1&foo2Param=foo2```.

Comment: Interestingly I can't get your route to work either. If I change the action name to Index I end up with ```https://hostname/foocontroller?page=2&foo1Param=foo1&foo2Param=foo2```. I have this configured in my startup too ```app.UseRouting();``` and ```app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
               endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });``` edited original question to include this info.

Comment: I can't get this working in a new solution either. @ZhiLv do you have the full razor code for the pager you're using please? Mine is ```@using X.PagedList; @*import this so we can cast our list to IPagedList (only necessary because ViewBag is dynamic)*@
@model IPagedList<FooModel>;
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core; @*import this so we get our HTML Helper*@
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, foo1Param = "foo1", foo2Param = "foo2" }))```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `page =>` with `pagenumber =>`. It worked for me. In my case, it seems that the problem was the usage of `page` keyword. Maybe it's interpreted as Razor Page.